# What is the difference between `tuple(None)` and `(None,)`?

Tags: python

I need to return a tuple of 1 object (my function is among a class of functions that are all expected to return a tuple of 1+ objects). The object I'm returning might be `None`, but still needs to be wrapped in a tuple for consistency. One way to do this is:

```
return (possibly_none_object,)
```

But I always found that syntax with the lingering comma to be awkward, so I thought I'd do it this way:

```
return tuple(possible_none_object)
```

I thought that would do exactly the same thing and be more explicit.

But the second line throws `{TypeError} 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. That got me to wondering why these two statements were different and what elusive detail I might be missing in my understanding of python and tuples.

This might be a trivial question and answer, but I'm curious.

Comment: `tuple(x)` converts `x` to a tuple; it doesn’t create a tuple of its arguments. Same with `list(x)` (does not mean `[x]`), `set(x)` (does not mean `{x}`)…. Also, use the trailing comma, it’s standard. (See `repr(tuple([1]))`.)

Comment: @Ry- got the point. In fact you can try `x = 2; tuple(x)` to get the same error. `tuple()` is a conversion function, not a wrapping function.

Comment: Also, when you’re wondering how a function works, try help in the REPL: `help(tuple)`.

Comment: `(None,)` might well be awkward if you are coming from another language, but it soon becomes natural when using Python.  The comma is needed because `(None)` is just `None`.  Bare `()` are used to group operators, but are otherwise ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tuple(x)` requires x to be of type iterable

so for example `tuple('a', 'b')` does not work but `tuple(['a', 'b'])` does

So `tuple([None])` is equivalent to `(None,)`

Comment: I don't agree with the last statement. What's wrong with `(None,)`, i.e. what OP has already?

Comment: @jpp: Typo for “produce”. The answer explains how to get `(None,)` using `tuple`.

Comment: @Ry-, Got it, I think the last line needs clarification, though. At the very least, emphasis that this is what you'd do *if* you've convinced yourself you need to use `tuple([...])`. When, in reality, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot accept the lingering comma even if it is standard, you will only make it more complicated.

`tuple` accepts a iterable object and convert it into a tuple. So you can accomplish what you need by `tuple([possible_none_object])`. But isn't is more awkward? Rudendant brackets and an additionally created list.

Or you can make it even more complicated by using a decorator which hides that lingering comma for you:

```
def ensure_tuple(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(result, tuple):
            return (result,)
        return result
    return wrapper
```